# Views not being displayed in a non-default configuration using Phalcon

Tags: php, url, phalcon

I generated a project using, phalcon tools. In the config.php I changes view to:

```
'viewsDir'       => APP_PATH . '/views/test/',
```

I have created two controllers: `ExampleController` and `TestController`

I have links pointing to `http://example.com/test` and `http://example.com/test`

In the views folder I have placed 2 files, one in `views/test/example/example.phtml` and another in `views/test/test/test.phtml` when I try to go to the links I get a blank page, if I move the phtml files in folder views/test/ the view that is loaded is the index.phml no matter which of the 2 url's I go to (this is the page that displays the 2 links above). If I echo out from the controllers this is displayed so the controllers are being accessed just the view are not being displayed. Please can someone advise? (Nb. If I use the default view configuration, then the views are being displayed)

Answer (score 0):

You should place an index.phtml file in both directories. Thats the page that's loaded once you point to the respective controller. If you want it to load e.g example.phtml, you have to create an action called exampleAction in ExampleController. Then call it via http://example.com/example/example.